# How can I elliptically truncate text in golang?

Tags: string, go, truncate

I'd like to be able to cleanly cut a paragraph larger than certain number of characters without cutting a word in the middle.

So for example this:

> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the
>   readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of
>   using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of
>   letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it
>   look like readable English.

Should become:

> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the
>   readable content ...

Here is the function that I came up with:

```
 func truncateText(s string, max int) string {
    if len(s) > max {
        r := 0
        for i := range s {
            r++
            if r > max {
                return s[:i]
            }
        }
    }
    return s
}
```

But it just brutally cuts the text. I'm wondering how can I modify (or replace it with a better solution) in order to cut the text elliptically?

Comment: Nice use of the word `elliptically` :o)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Slicing strings can be problematic because slicing works with bytes, not runes. Range, however, works with runes:

```
lastSpaceIx:=-1
len:=0
for i,r:=range str {
  if unicode.IsSpace(r) {
     lastSpaceIx=i
  }
  len++
  if len>=max {
    if lastSpaceIx!=-1 {
        return str[:lastSpaceIx]+"..."
    }
    // If here, string is longer than max, but has no spaces
  }
}
// If here, string is shorter than max
```

Answer (score 6):

The range is totally unnecessary as written; as it is now, your whole function could just be:

```
func truncateText(s string, max int) string {
    return s[:max]
}
```

Which is so simple it shouldn't even be a function; but of course it also will cut off words, which you said you don't want. So instead you could:

```
func truncateText(s string, max int) string {
    if max > len(s) {
        return s
    }
    return s[:strings.LastIndex(s[:max]," ")]
}
```

Or if you want to use multiple characters as word boundaries not just spaces:

```
func truncateText(s string, max int) string {
    if max > len(s) {
        return s
    }
    return s[:strings.LastIndexAny(s[:max]," .,:;-")]
}
```

Comment: This is probably not multi-byte safe.

Comment: @BurakSerdar what do you mean?

Comment: String slice operations treat strings like a slice of bytes. If the string has multi-byte characters, s[:max] would not be the right place to cut it.

Comment: @Adrian, thanks for the tip but this has some shortcomings: 1. gives error when there is newline in string. 2. panics when the text length is shorter than `max`.

Comment: @BurakSerdar what is your solution?

Comment: [This](https://go.dev/play/p/SWY4Lu5Ano5) seems to handle multi-byte strings

Comment: Your first function `s[:max]` will panic if length is less that `max`.

Answer (score 3):

I improved on the answer from Burak. This implementation returns the exact input string if `len(text)=maxLen` instead of adding an ellipsis, and if text has no spaces, it just does a hard truncation at `maxLen`.

```
func EllipticalTruncate(text string, maxLen int) string {
    lastSpaceIx := maxLen
    len := 0
    for i, r := range text {
        if unicode.IsSpace(r) {
            lastSpaceIx = i
        }
        len++
        if len > maxLen {
            return text[:lastSpaceIx] + "..."
        }
    }
    // If here, string is shorter or equal to maxLen
    return text
}
```

Test Case

```
func TestEllipticalTruncate(t *testing.T) {
    assert.Equal(t, "...", EllipticalTruncate("1 2 3", 0))
    assert.Equal(t, "1...", EllipticalTruncate("1 2 3", 1))
    assert.Equal(t, "1...", EllipticalTruncate("1 2 3", 2))
    assert.Equal(t, "1 2...", EllipticalTruncate("1 2 3", 3))
    assert.Equal(t, "1 2 3", EllipticalTruncate("1 2 3", 5))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution avoids range but takes multibytes runes into account:

```
func ellipsis(s string, maxLen int) string {
    runes := []rune(s)
    if len(runes) <= maxLen {
        return s
    }
    if maxLen < 3 {
        maxLen = 3
    }
    return string(runes[0:maxLen-3]) + "..."
}
```

See https://go.dev/play/p/ibj6aK7N0rc

Comment: This is a good answer for those looking to truncate safely without respecting word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I offer very simple variant.

https://go.dev/play/p/Pbk5DchjReT

```golang
func ShortText(s string, i int) string {
    if len(s) < i {
        return s
    }

    if utf8.ValidString(s[:i]) {
        return s[:i]
    }
    return s[:i+1]

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Doesn't work with 3- or 4-byte runes.

Answer (score -2):

To split according to whitespace and more, you can use regex :

```golang
func splitString(str string) []string {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("[\\s\\n\\t\\r ]+") //split according to \s, \t, \r, \t and whitespace. Edit this regex for other 'conditions'

    split := re.Split(str, -1)
    return split
}

func main() {
    var s = "It is a long\nestablished fact that a reader\nwill\nbe distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English."
    var maxLen = 40

    arr := splitString(s)

    totalLen := 0
    finalStr := ``
    for _, each := range arr {
        if (totalLen + len(each) > maxLen) {
            fmt.Print(strings.TrimSpace(finalStr) + `...`)
            break
        }
        totalLen += len(each)
        finalStr += each + ` `

    }
}
```

---

//Old 2

You can do this kind of things : Split your string in slice and loop through the slice until the total length of your string is above the max allowed length.

```golang
    var s = "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English."
    var maxLen = 30

    arr := strings.SplitAfter(s, ` `)

    totalLen := 0
    finalStr := ``
    for _, each := range arr {
        if (totalLen + len(each) > maxLen) {
            fmt.Print(strings.TrimSpace(finalStr) + `...`)
            break
        }
        totalLen += len(each)
        finalStr += each

    }
```

It is a long established fact...

---

//old bad answer
You have to work with strings and slices :

```golang
    var s = "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English."

    newS := s[:30 - 3] 
    newS += `...`
    fmt.Print(newS)
```

Result : `It is a long established fa...`

Comment: First line of the question: "I'd like to be able to cleanly cut a paragraph larger than certain number of characters without cutting a word in the middle."

Comment: My bad, I updated my answer with a working solution

Comment: Easy to understand, but does not take care of situation where there is newline in the text. So not robust enough.

Comment: If you want to split on whitespace, newline, tab, etc. you need to split the original string after the wanted values. I updated my original answer.